# Ignore .orig files in build

Tags: android, gradle

Using mercurial for version control, and a conflict arose with my strings.xml file. I resolved the conflict with a file compare tool, and it created a .orig file.

I know there isn't a whole lot of reason to keep the .orig file, but I would like to keep it for a short period in case I made a mistake somewhere.

Unfortunately, Gradle fails at building because it is detecting duplicate strings in strings.xml and strings.xml.orig when it's on the task mergeDebugResources.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
> [DIRECTORY]\src\main\res\values\strings.xml.orig: Error: Duplicate resources:  [DIRECTORY]\src\main\res\values\strings.xml.orig:string/navigation_drawer_close, [DIRECTORY]\src\main\res\values\strings.xml:string/navigation_drawer_close
```

This really shouldn't generate an error in the first place I wouldn't think; but how do I configure gradle to just ignore all .orig files?

Comment: Simple solution is not to keep `.orig` files under source control. Your repo will remember.

Comment: The .orig files aren't in source control, but they were created when resolving a conflict. But now gradle is looking at them when trying to build my project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the `mergeDebugResources` task. If it is a type of Copy task, you could try adding this at configuration time:

```
exclude '**/*.orig'
```